# Store a Row Range/List

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, row

1. Trying to create a row range/list that stores all the row numbers with values in column A.
   When I run the code I get the last VarRow() -> last row number instead of the entire range/list.
2. Many times, I could not run through `VarRow(VarCount) = z + 1`.
   It stops at the row when the cell has the value so I cannot finish going to the next line of code (shows Subscript out of range).

```vb
Dim VarRow() As Double

VarCount = 0
VarCount2 = 0

For z = 1 To 350
    If Range("A1").Offset(z, 0).Value <> 0 Then
        VarCount = VarCount + 1
    End If
Next z
                     
ReDim Preserve VarRow(VaCount2)
                    
For z = 1 To 350
    If Range("A1").Offset(z, 0).Value <> 0 Then
        VarCount2 = VarCount2 + 1
        VarRow(VarCount) = z + 1
    End If
Next z
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through the Rows of a One-Column Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RowNumbersToArray()
    
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim RowNumbers() As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For r = fRow To lRow
        If ws.Cells(r, Col).Value <> 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve RowNumbers(0 To n)
            RowNumbers(n) = r
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next r
                         
    For n = 0 To n - 1
        Debug.Print n, RowNumbers(n)
    Next n
                         
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks so much for your reponse!! I am trying to update the code  "If ws.Cells(r, Col).Value <> 0 Then    RowNumbers(n) = r" to "If Ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = VarRange(j) Then RowNumbers(j) = r" so that I can match a list of variables (revenue, expense, depreciation....) I stored in the VarRange (j). I keep getting the error "Subscript out or range" error. Do you know what might be the reason for that? Thanks again for your help.